Nvidia Wayland Ubuntu animation is not smooth
sorry for my bad english. I had a computer with an AMD graphics card and it did not have the problem I am talking about.Now I Have 3050 and If I plug in two monitors the animations get worse.There is no problem with a single monitor, but with two monitors, GNOME animations or Hyprland animations start to lag, and this problem is not only in Gnome. It also happens in Hyprland. I tried the open-kernel driver, but it didn't help. As far as I read, Wayland and Nvidia are incompatible. Is there another way?
